# How does one do instance level model validation in Play 2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I need some complex validation logic which would be across multiple fields. Is there a way to do this every time save() or update() on a model is called? I m currently using Ebean as my ORM. The only way I can think of right now is to override save() like:

```
public class User extends Model {
  @Override
  public void save(){
    if(this.validate()){
      super.save();
    }
  }
 ..
}
```

Is there a more standardized way to do this?

Comment: How about standard way for handling binding failures? http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaForms it allows for more clever error maintenance.

Comment: I m not really using HTTP forms. Also, the data in my request does not match 1:1 with my model. Isnt there a way for me to do this in the model?

Comment: Nope, validation expects that fields with constraints exist in the request (you don't need to use form, but you need name the params as it was the form)

Comment: Well then maybe I just do it like I mentioned above. I am using @Constraints on my fields but cross-field validation must happen somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to watch BeanPersistAdapter in ebean.

you can override methods, such as preUpdate.